# Definitions of Milnor number

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ be a function with an isolated singularity at $0$, by which I mean $f'(0)=0$ and there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f'(p)\not = 0$ for all $p$ nonzero with $|p|<\epsilon$.

The $\textbf{Milnor number}$ of $f$ at $0$ can be defined in two ways:

i) The dimension, as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, of the 'local algebra' $\mathbb{C}[z_1,...,z_n]/\langle\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial z_1}, ..., \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial z_n}\rangle$ (the algebra of functions modulo the ideal generated by the partial derivatives of $f$).

ii) The degree of the map from $\mathbb{S}_\epsilon^{2n+1}\to \mathbb{S}_\epsilon^{2n+1}$ defined by $z\mapsto \epsilon \frac{\left(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial z_1}, ..., \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial z_n}\right)}{\|\left(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial z_1}, ..., \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial z_n}\right)\|}$ (the 'normalized gradient' of $f$).

Why are these two definitions equivalent? I am aware of how to get from (ii) to (iii) = 'the middle Betti number of the Milnor fiber', so I would also be happy with an answer relating this to (i).

Any hint or reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F$ be the Milnor fiber of the germ of $f$ near $0$. As you have assumed
that $0$ is an isolated critical point, it is known that $F$ is homotopy
equivalent to a wedge sum of spheres $S^{n-1}$. In particular, the cohomology of
$F$ is concentrated in degree $n-1$. Let $\mu'$ be this number.

The question is why this number is equal to the dimension of the artinian
algebra $\mathbb{C}[\![z_1,\ldots,z_n]\!]/J$, where $J$ is the ideal generated
by $\partial f/\partial z_i$, $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

*Note*. In your original question, you used the polynomial ring instead of the power series
ring. This is not correct. The polynomial $f$ may have other critical points
other than $0$, which will contribute to the quotient (if other critical points
are not isolated, the quotient algebra is not finite dimensional). As an
example, check the polynomial $f(x,y)=xy(x+y-1)$. To get the correct answer,
there are some options, you could use: (i) the formal
power series ring as above; or (ii) the ring of germs of analytic functions
around $0$; or (iii) the ring $\mathcal{O}(B)$ of analytic functions on a small neighborhood $B$ of
$0$ in which there are no other critical points.

Morally, a topological argument goes as follows
(I believe this was Milnor's argument in his book
"singular points of complex hypersurfaces"):
one uses the interpretation (iii) above of the Milnor number $\mu$, and
deforms the function $f$ to $f_{\epsilon}$, such that

- the critical points of $f_{\epsilon}$ are at worst double points, and
- the dimension of the artin ring
  $\mathcal{O}(B)/(\partial_{i}f_{\epsilon},i=1,2,\ldots,n)$
  remains constant.

In this deformation the wedge sum of vanishing spheres "splits" into a disjoint union of spheres,
one for each critical point of $f_{\epsilon}$. Thus, it reduces to proving the theorem
for a Morse critical point, which is obvious.

Another proof, essentially an algebraization of the topological method,
is recorded in SGA 7, Exposé XVI.
Again, one first checks that the theorem holds if
$0$ is an ordinary double point, which is rather straightforward.
The "deformation" step in the topological argument is now replaced
by a "globalization", where one can use global theorems such as Gauss--Bonnet
and Grothendieck--Ogg--Shafarevich.

One can find a morphism
$$
g\colon X \to \mathbb{P}^{1}
$$
where $X$ is a nonsingular projective variety, $g$ a morphism,
such that (SGA 7, Exposé XVI, Proposition 2.5)

1. $g$ has only isolated critical points,
2. each fiber $g^{-1}(t)$ has at most one singular point,
3. in the formal completion of one critical point $x_0$
   (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[\![z_1,\ldots,z_n]\!]$)
   the expansion of $g$ equals $f$,
4. all the critical points other than $x_0$ are ordinary double points.

The construction of such a global model uses some algebraic geometry, but is
not difficult.

Now the upshot is to calculate the Euler characteristic of $X$ by two methods.
First one calculates $\int_X c_n(\Theta_X)$, and gets
(see SGA 7, Exposé XVI, Proposition 2.1)
$$
\chi(X) = \chi(f^{-1}\eta) \chi(\mathbb{P}^1) - (-1)^{n-1}\sum \mu_{x}
$$
where $\eta$ is a generic point of $\mathbb{P}^1$,
$x$ ranges in the set of all critical points of $g$.

On the other hand, we can invoke the Grothendieck--Ogg--Shafarevich formula,
which states
$$
\chi(X) = \chi(f^{-1}\eta) \chi(\mathbb{P}^1) - \sum \Phi_{x} 
$$
where $\Phi_x$ is the Euler characteristic of the "Milnor fiber" around $x$
(i.e., the Euler characteristic of the vanishing cycle complex).
Comparing the two displayed equation, using the condition (4)
and the equality for double points, the desired formula follows.

Comment: What exactly should I learn from the example $f(x,y) = xy(x+y-1)$? I think the quotient algebra is 4-dimensional, but I guess the crossing at $0$ is very nice, it should be 1-dimensional (ignoring the $(x+y-1)$ part).

Comment: The algebraic geometry language is a bit much for me. Do you know where specifically in Milnor this is? In an appendix he shows you can perturb to get only double points, but I don't see why the dimension remains constant @Function

Comment: Having a quick look at Milnor's book, I found he was using the
"local degree" definition; he is counting how many points "near" $0\in\mathbb{C}^n$ are sent to a point $t$  near $0 \in\mathbb{C}$ via the map $z \mapsto \partial_1 f, \ldots,\partial_n f$, in order to avoid directly counting how many times 0 is sent to 0. In AG, counting can be made if mulitplicities are taken into consideration. The local
multiplicity of a map $z \mapsto (f_1(z), \ldots, f_n(z)) \colon \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$
at $z=0$ is the length of the ring $\mathbb{C}[\![z]\!]/(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$.

Comment: I think that last line is precisely my confusion though. I understand 'local multiplicity' in the topological sense, counting preimages of a generic value, but how does that relate to the algebraic data?

Comment: One should use the language of schemes: in a finite flat family,
the length of the scheme-theoretic fibers is constant.
Example: consider $z\mapsto t=z^2\colon \mathbb{C}_z \to \mathbb{C}_t$.
This is induced by the ring homomorphism $t\mapsto z^2\colon\mathbb{C}[t] \to\mathbb{C}[z]$.
If $t_0 \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, then the fiber over $t_0$ corresponds to the
ring $\mathbb{C}[z]/(z^2-t_0) \cong \mathbb{C}^2$, which is reduced of length 2.
But if $t_0=0$, the fiber at $0$, as a scheme, corresponds to the ring
$\mathbb{C}[z]/(z^2)$, which is still of length 2, but is non-reduced.